# Change the content of a Word Document with Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, ms-word, coldfusion-9, openoffice.org

I have a bunch of Word documents with text wrapped in brackets.  I need to replace this text with metadata about specific individuals.  Example below:

Dear [firstname] [lastname], 
blah blah blah

If I read the file content (FileRead(worddoc)) and then do a replace on the bracketed info, it only works if the number of characters I replace exactly match.  So, if I replace [firstname] with Franksteines it works (both are 11 characters).  If it isn't the same number of characters, it does not.

By *it doesn't work* I mean, Microsoft and OpenOffice think the document is corrupt.  If I open the document in Notepad++ I see that the data has been correctly replaced, but the file is corrupt, unless the number of characters replaced exactly match the original number of characters.

Does anyone know if, in CF 9 there is a way to leverage OpenOffice to do this type of thing?

Comment: Ouch, I've only used HTML templates that I do text replace with and then farm out to convert to a PDF or RTF.  The text replace approach works fine for that.  If you want to do this properly with Office products, you have to use their MailMerge feature, not just a simple text replace.  Not sure of CF support for that...

Comment: Here is a like I found describing what is supported: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/161787